# How to check if WEP authetication is failed in linux

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

If using the WEP security in open mode, then how can client running Linux kernel can check that Authentication is failed because of wrong key, but association was successful because it's an WEP open mode.

Comment: Detail a bit more what you do...

Comment: just ping a host o try to receive some data.

Answer (score 0):

You will see this in wpa_supplican's log. It will look somehow like this (sorry, just random example I found in Internet):

```
[  778.327092] wlan0: associated
[  778.332503] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready 
[  788.334222] wlan0: disassociating from 00:1c:f0:b1:80:6a by local choice (reason=3) 
[  788.341433] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US 
[  788.342348] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:1c:f0:b1:80:6a by local choice (reason=3) 
[  789.122029] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present 
[  789.263341] wlan0: authenticate with 00:1c:f0:b1:80:6a (try 1) 
[  789.463049] wlan0: authenticate with 00:1c:f0:b1:80:6a (try 2) 
[  789.663048] wlan0: authenticate with 00:1c:f0:b1:80:6a (try 3) 
[  789.863057] wlan0: authentication with 00:1c:f0:b1:80:6a timed out
```

As you could see from the log above, client has been successfully associated (778.327092), but failed on the authentication stage (789.863057).

You could also use *wpa_cli* and its 'status' command:

```
> status 
bssid=00:1c:f0:b1:80:6a 
ssid=KLUK2 
id=1 
mode=station 
pairwise_cipher=NONE 
group_cipher=NONE 
key_mgmt=IEEE 802.1X (no WPA) 
wpa_state=ASSOCIATED 
Supplicant PAE state=CONNECTING 
suppPortStatus=Unauthorized 
EAP state=IDLE 
<2>Authentication with 00:1c:f0:b1:80:6a timed out. 
> <2>CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=3 
> <2>CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=3 
> <2>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
> <2>Trying to authenticate with 00:1c:f0:b1:80:6a (SSID='KLUK2' freq=2437 MHz) 
<2>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
<2>CTRL-EVENT-BSS-REMOVED 0 00:1d:19:cd:43:a1 
> <2>CTRL-EVENT-BSS-REMOVED 1 00:24:fe:82:ea:d9 
> <2>CTRL-EVENT-BSS-REMOVED 2 00:04:0e:8e:a7:fe 
> <2>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
```